# Using Label property of Office Ribbon Control in vba

Tags: vba, callback, ribbon, office-2007

Is there a way to read/get the Label attribute of an Office 2007/2010 ribbon control in VBA? The only exposed properties *appear* to be Tag, ID, and Context.

I'm trying to use the getLabel and getVisible callbacks together--read the label and determine whether or not to show a control. I tried setting the Tag property in the getLabel callback, but the code won't compile as that property is read-only by then.

Any other suggestions for how to skin this cat welcome. Note that I cannot use a dynamic menu; this is under a split button, and has to stay there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "tumbleweed" badge should be renamed "crickets..."

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that VBA doesn't have access to customize the Ribbon UI. I do know for a fact that this can be handled with VSTO.

Comment: I don't think the problem has anything to do with VBA vs. VSTO, but rather with the fact that the ribbon object doesn't expose those callbacks to each other. I'd be happy to take a look at some working VSTO code, but I doubt it can alter the ribbon object model any better than VBA can.

Comment: I've been reading up on this all morning. You're right...it's not a VBA vs. VSTO problem. You might find your solution at the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee390805(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: I've seen that before, but it doesn't help to combine label reading and visibility setting. There doesn't seem to be any way to read the label at runtime, let alone when the label has itself been set by getLabel